# What photo management application can I migrate to that would preserve iPhoto's face detection data?

Tags: software-recommendation, photos.app, photos, migration

I've used iPhoto for many years and found that it was suitable for what I wanted to do. Since Apple has discontinued iPhoto and Aperature in favor of their new Photos application, I'm seriously considering switching applications for my photo management since I'm just not happy with the direction they're taking the software. All well and good, but the annoying thing is that I've spent hours of my time working with the face detection feature of iPhoto and I'd hate to lose all the work tweaking the exception cases (i.e. iPhoto couldn't make out who someone was and I had to manually tell it).

For what its worth, I'm still on iPhoto '09 as iPhoto '11 didn't seem like that much of an improvement to me; in fact, the removal of the LAN sharing and obfuscated context menu items (e.g. reveal in finder type functions) stopped me from upgrading.

Are there any applications out there which I can migrate to which would preserve all the face data from iPhoto '09?

Comment: I'm assuming you really mean to migrate the data on faces as opposed to just exporting the photos and/or tagging them with the faces named.

Comment: @bmike, yes - you've got the spirit of it. I've spent a lot of time helping iPhoto figure out who was who and I'd hate for all that work to be lost as I eventually move away from iPhoto. I'd trust that the new Photos.app would preserve this information, but I'm not sure I'm sold on it as my migration path past iPhoto '09.

Comment: You should sign up for the public preview of Photos and submit feedback if it doesn't preserve your face data. I couldn't comment on my thoughts about what will happen, but the more people that test a specific feature, the more likely it will work at general release. https://appleseed.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/ You'll want to install the beta onto a USB drive and/or have a known good and restorable backup before jumping in...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it yet, but apparently the new Photos app will continue the face detection or 'Faces' work they've had for some time in iPhoto and Aperture:

http://www.cheatsheet.com/technology/how-apple-is-reinventing-iphoto-with-the-new-mac-photos-app.html/?a=viewall

[image: faces detail]

Comment: I'm down voting since this tool isn't finished and the article just says that face detection works in Photos - not that it will import that data or organization from Aperture or iPhoto. Better to wait until you've used it to guess if/how it works.

Comment: @bmike Photos is a step forward in face recognition with respect to iPhoto, and indeed keeps the face detection, and can use it to find not classified faces, and new faces.